# Countdown timer for different time zones

Tags: javascript

I need to develop a countdown timer hour for the company offices:

One office is in Brazil and the other is in Japan

Brazil = UTC-03:00
JAPAN = UTC+09:00

Both offices open at 8 AM and closes 8 PM, when Brazilian office is opening, the Japanese office is closing.

How can i configure to a japanese see the brazilian office closed and japanese office open and vice versa

Follow the link: http://lickslegal.webflow.io/teste/relogio

My javascript code:

```
function getTimeRemaining(endtime){

  var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
  var seconds = Math.floor( (t/1000) % 60 );
  var minutes = Math.floor( (t/1000/60) % 60 );
  var hours = Math.floor( (t/(1000*60*60)) % 24 );
  var days = Math.floor( t/(1000*60*60*24) );
  return {
    'total': t,
    'days': days,
    'hours': hours,
    'minutes': minutes,
    'seconds': seconds
  };
}


function initializeClock(endtime, clock_location, status, add_class, remove_class){

  clock_location.find('.relogio_status').removeClass(remove_class);
  clock_location.find('.relogio_status').addClass(add_class);

  var timeinterval = setInterval(function(){
    var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);

    var show_message = ' '+status+' in ';

    if (t.days > 0) {
        show_message += t.days+" d ";
    }

    show_message += (t.hours < 10 ? '0':'')+t.hours+":"+(t.minutes < 10 ? '0':'')+t.minutes+":"+(t.seconds < 10 ? '0':'')+t.seconds;

    clock_location.find('.status_clock_text').html(show_message);

    if(t.total==0){
      // clearInterval(timeinterval);
      // location.reload();
      clock_city('rio_de_janeiro');
    }
  },1000);
}


function when_monday(){
    var will_monday = new Date();
    will_monday.setDate(will_monday.getDate() + (1 + 7 - will_monday.getDay()) % 7);

    return {
        'year': will_monday.getFullYear(),
        'month': (will_monday.getMonth() +1),
        'date': will_monday.getDate(),
        'full': will_monday,
        'open_or_close': will_monday.getFullYear()+"-"+(will_monday.getMonth() +1)+"-"+will_monday.getDate()
    };
}

function go_tomorrow(){
    var tomorrow = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

    return {
        'year': tomorrow.getFullYear(),
        'month': (tomorrow.getMonth() +1),
        'date': tomorrow.getDate(),
        'full': tomorrow,
        'open_or_close': tomorrow.getFullYear()+"-"+(tomorrow.getMonth() +1)+"-"+tomorrow.getDate()
    };
}


function clock_city(city_id){
    var today = new Date();

    var y = today.getFullYear();
    var m = (today.getMonth() +1);
    var d = today.getDate();

    var location_city = $("#"+city_id);

    var city_open_time = location_city.find('.open_time').text();
    var city_close_time = location_city.find('.close_time').text();
    var city_close_date = location_city.find('.close_date').text();

    // var city_open_deadline = y+"-"+m+"-"+d+" "+city_open_time;
    var city_close_deadline = y+"-"+m+"-"+d+" "+city_close_time;



    var hora_atual = (today.getHours() < 10 ? '0':'')+today.getHours()+':'+today.getMinutes();

    if (hora_atual >= city_open_time && hora_atual < city_close_time){
        //ABERTO
        console.log('aberto');
        initializeClock(city_close_deadline, location_city, 'closing', 'office_open', 'office_closed');
    }else{
        //FECHADO
        console.log('fechado');

        //Verifica se for SEXTA ou FDS
        if ( (today.getDay() +1) == 6 || today.getDay() == 6 || today.getDay() == 0) {  
            var city_open_deadline = when_monday().open_or_close+" "+city_open_time;
        }else{
            var city_open_deadline = go_tomorrow().open_or_close+" "+city_open_time;
        }
        initializeClock(city_open_deadline, location_city, 'opening', 'office_closed', 'office_open');
    }
}


$(document).ready(function() {
    clock_city('rio_de_janeiro');
    clock_city('tokyo');
});
```

Comment: define "the correct countdown" first. Countdown to what?

Comment: Obligatory [XKCD quote](https://xkcd.com/1883/)

Comment: you're definitely gonna wanna use moment https://momentjs.com/timezone/

Answer (score 1):

Part of the problem is your site says the Brazil office hours are from 08:00 to 20:00 and the Japan office hours are from 08:00 to 20:00. Neither of these ranges is correct. Brazil office hours are 11:00 to 23:00 and Japan office hours are 23:00 to 11:00. As a general rule, use UTC everywhere except the final display.

`new Date()` generates a Date object holding the current date, in UTC. With your reference times also in UTC, no conversion is needed to find the time remaining. Since you don't actually care about dates, only durations, you don't need to make any timezone adjustments for the output.

Answer (score 1):

The UTC offset can be added to the current UTC date and time:

```js
console.log( 'Z+0:',           new Date            )  // current UTC time
console.log( 'Z-3:', new Date( new Date -3 * 36e5) )  // current UTC time minus 3 hours
console.log( 'Z+8:', new Date(+new Date +8 * 36e5) )  // + used to convert to number

console.log( 'Tests:' )
console.log( 'Z+0:',           new Date(0)            )  // "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
console.log( 'Z-3:', new Date( new Date(0) -3 * 36e5) )  // "1969-12-31T21:00:00.000Z"
console.log( 'Z+8:', new Date(+new Date(0) +8 * 36e5) )  // "1970-01-01T08:00:00.000Z"
```